# (Excel) Is there a way in Excel to dynamically concatenate a single cell based on the value of another cell?

Tags: excel

For example I have in

Cell A1: ABC

Cell B1: 3

I want Cell C1 to return ABC 3 times in a single cell.

I have a formula in Cell C1 with TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1,A1,A1) but I want a way to do this dynamically based on the value in B1 since that can range from 2 to 20. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in function for this:

```
=REPT(A1,B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Did not know this. I ended up with Concatenating CHAR(10) to A1 and then using the REPT function with B1 so I get the line break. Thanks so much!